# Which calls to unapply can be replaced with parentheses?

Tags: scala

So I have known that in Scala you can replace calls to Tuple.unapply with parentheses. 
For instance

```
val tuple: Tuple2[Int, Int] = (1, 2)
val (x, _) = tuple
println(x) //prints 1
```

However, I recently found out that the following code compiles (although crashes when run, but let's ignore that):

```
val tuple: Product2[Int, Int] = ???
val (x, _) = tuple
println(x)
```

So it turns out that calls to Product2.unapply() can be replaced with parentheses. Are there any other classes that can do that?

Comment: The parens are actually a syntax shorthand for the `TupleX` objects, that's what you see here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the [`Tuple2`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Tuple2) Scala documentation :

> A tuple of 2 elements; the canonical representation of a [`scala.Product2`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Product2).

When you do `val (x, _) = tuple`, `Tuple2.unapply` is still called since you try to pattern match for a tuple, with `(x, _)` being a more ideomatic alternative to `Tuple2(x, _)`.

```
val tuple = (1, 2)
val product: Product2[Int, Int] = tuple
val (a, b) = product
// a: Int = 1
// b: Int = 2
```

You could pattern match using [`Product2.unapply`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Product2$@unapply[T1,T2]%28x:Product2[T1,T2]%29:Option[Product2[T1,T2]]) :

```
val Product2(a, b) = product
// a: Int = 1
// b: Int = 2
```

Pattern matching a `Tuple2` when you have a `Product2` is simalar to :

```
val list = List(1, 2)
val seq: Seq[Int] = list
val List(a, b) = seq
```

Which also only compiles when `seq` is a `List`, if we created `seq` as a `Vector` this doesn't compile :

```
val seq: Seq[Int] = Vector(1, 2)
val List(a, b) = seq
```

Answer (score 1):

About your question "Are there any other classes that can do that?", the answer is yes. Basically you can use that syntax with every class for which it is defined a companion object with an `unapply` method. For example, with a `case class` you get that automatically. E.g.:

```
scala> case class Foo(a: String, b: Int, c: String)
defined class Foo

scala> val foo = Foo("hello", 42, "world")
foo: Foo = Foo(hello,42,world)

scala> val Foo(a, _, c) = foo
a: String = hello
c: String = world
```

As you can see you have to specify the type, you cannot just use it this way:

```
scala> val (a, _, c) = foo
<console>:12: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : (T1, T2, T3)
 required: Foo
       val (a, _, c) = foo
           ^
```

The error is basically saying that you have a `Tuple3` on the lhs and a `Foo` on the rhs, so the expression doesn't *type check*. The reason is that `(a, b, c)` is actually syntactic sugar for `Tuple3(a, b, c)`:

```
scala> val (a, b, c) = ("hello", 42, "world")
a: String = hello
b: Int = 42
c: String = world

scala> val Tuple3(a, b, c) = ("hello", 42, "world")
a: String = hello
b: Int = 42
c: String = world
```

As I said at the beginning of the answer you can also implement your own *extractors* by defining a custom `unapply` method within the companion object of your class.